# Number of Combinations : picking exactly one element from each set .

Tags: combinatorics

Given the sets of numbers (1,2,3) , (1,4,6,8) and (1,2,7,8,10).
How many ways are there to choose exactly one element from each set.

NOTE: If we choose 2 from the first set we don't choose any element from third set because 2 also exists in the third set. 
Also,the selection (1,1,2) is not allowed(we have selected 1 from first set and its also present in third set. So if we choose 2 from third set , this will mean that we have selected two elements from the third set).

Also , how to solve the generalised question:
 Given 'N' sets. Sets may have non-empty intersections. How many ways are there to choose exactly one element from each set.

Comment: @SS_C4 we cannot do that, take (1,2,3) and (4,5). No of ways of picking two elements would be 3*2=6 . But if we take union then answer would be 5C2 =10

Comment: Asking how many ways there are to choose exactly one element in each set allows the selection $(1, 1, 1)$.  However, your note suggests that was not your intention.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig choosing 1 from a set means that we have to only one choice then , that is (1,1,1). What I meant though was, (1,1,2) is not possible(we have selected 1 from first set and its also present in third set. So if we choose 2 from third set , this will mean that we have selected two elements from the third set).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have 3 sets: A, B, and C.

Let $a=|A-B\cup C|, \;\;b=|B-A\cup C|,\;\; c=|C-A\cup B|$ and

let $\;d=|A\cap B-C|, \;\;e=|A\cap C-B|, \;\;f=|B\cap C-A|,\;\;g=|A\cap B\cap C|$.

We can either choose 3 distinct elements, one element repeated twice and then a second element, or one element repeated 3 times; so this gives a total of

$\hspace{.4 in}\color{blue}{abc+(dc+eb+fa)+g}$ selections.

---

In this example, we get $1\cdot2\cdot2+0\cdot2+1\cdot2+1\cdot1+1=8$ selections.

Comment: Is it the only way of doing it ? . If it is,can you suggest how to make it computationally easier, because for the generalised problem we will have to find elements that are distinct,repeated once,twice....n times (which is computationally costly).

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it computationally easier -- perhaps this would be a good question for cs.stackexchange